# $\lim_{x\to \infty} [{\sqrt{(4x^2-2x)}+2x}]=[1/4]$ why?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this sum: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\sqrt{4x^2-x}+2x\right)=\dfrac 14$$ in a competitive examination. But they give the answer as $\dfrac 14$. As I have learnt, all I have to worry about limits that how I can eliminate the zero in the denominator. But here I haven't had a perfect limit and since $x\to\infty$ the denominator is zero but how can I get the numerator. Would you please tell me how to start the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the current form, I cannot figure out the numerator and denominator of the expression.

Comment: Learn to use Mathjax.

Comment: @AndrewLi is Mathjax a formula remembering App?

Comment: No, it's a mathematical formatting system for the browser: essentially LaTeX (JavaScript based).

Comment: Can you please say how can I learn this?

Comment: Question from KVPY?

Comment: @NetravatPendsey yes it's from KVPY

Comment: The answer is -1/4 if I remember correctly

Comment: @NetravatPendsey yes

Comment: But the problem is I can't put the negative sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\sqrt{4x^2-2x}+2x\sim 4x \to +\infty$$

while for $\sqrt{4x^2-2x}-2x$ note that by binomial expansion

- $\sqrt{4x^2-2x}=2x\left(1-\frac1{2x}\right)^{\frac12}\sim 2x\left(1-\frac1{4x}\right)=2x-\frac12$

and thus

$$\sqrt{4x^2-2x}-2x\sim 2x-\frac12-2x\to -\frac12$$

Comment: NB: I've corrected a sign error.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Gimusi you have showed me the correct criteria.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome, Bye!